# ColdFusion JavaScript equivalents for #encodeForJavaScript()#

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a few form fields that I am updating a DB through an ajax call.
The DB gets updated successfully but I can't get the form to update correctly if DoubleQuotes are submitted to the DB.

Say `Some "Quotes" are needed` was submitted as a subtask when Enter was pressed.

DB would see `Some "Quotes" are needed`.

But page would see `Some%20%22Quotes%22%20are%20needed` on focusout of the textbox if `encodeURI(data.TASKDESCRIPTION)` is used and.

If the page is refreshed page shows `Some "Quotes" are needed` successfully.

```
<cfif isDefined("action") and action is "editSubtask">
    <cfquery name="udpateSubTask" datasource="#siteDataSource#">
        UPDATE ProjectTaskSubtasks
        SET taskDescription = <cfqueryparam value="#form.TASKDESCRIPTION#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" >
        WHERE guid = <cfqueryparam value="#form.SUBTASKGUID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" >
    </cfquery>
    <cfquery name="selectSubTask" datasource="#siteDataSource#">
        SELECT guid as SUBTASKGUID, taskDescription
        FROM ProjectTaskSubtasks
        WHERE guid = <cfqueryparam value="#form.SUBTASKGUID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" >
        LIMIT 1
    </cfquery>
    <cfoutput>#serializeJSON(selectSubTask, "struct")#</cfoutput>
    <cfabort>
</cfif>
<!--- ----------------------------------------- --->
<cfloop query="#subtasks#">
    <div id="_#subtasks.guid#" class="col-xs-12">
        <input type="text" id="description-#subtasks.guid#" name="description-#subtasks.guid#" class="#subtasks.isComplete is 0 ? '' : 'strike'# subtask-hide col-xs-10" value="#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(subtasks.taskDescription)#" onClick="allowInput(this)"/>
        <!--- #EncodeForHTMLAttribute(subtasks.taskDescription)#  Works Great for the starting Value of this TextBox from DB especially if doublequotes in subtasks.taskDescription DB Field --->
    </div>
<!--- ----------------------------------------- --->
    <script>
    var taskDescription_#subtasks.guid# = "#encodeForJavaScript(subtasks.taskDescription)#";  //this appears to work as needed

    $('##description-#subtasks.guid#').keyup(function(e){
        var code = e.which;
        if(code===13){
            $.post(
                '#cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#',
                {
                    action: 'editSubtask',
                    SUBTASKGUID: $(this).parent()[0].id.replace('_',''),
                    TASKDESCRIPTION: $(this).val()
                },
                function(data){
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    data = data[0];

                    taskDescription_#subtasks.guid# = encodeURI(data.TASKDESCRIPTION);  //THIS DOES NOT WORK if doublequotes where submitted to the DB : when data comes back from editSubTask I need a way to update my Variable so on focus out it updates the field with the new information submitted .
                    $('##formButt').focus();
                }
            );
        }
    });

    $('##description-#subtasks.guid#').focusout(function(){
        /* .val(taskDescription_#subtasks.guid#)works great HERE on FocusOut doesn't change the Value from original var taskDescription_#subtasks.guid# = "#encodeForJavaScript(subtasks.taskDescription)#" */

        $('##description-#subtasks.guid#').val(taskDescription_#subtasks.guid#).removeClass('subtask').addClass('subtask-hide');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('##delete-#subtasks.guid#').removeClass('subtask-cancel').addClass('subtask-cancel-hide');
        },150)
    });
    </script>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Not understanding the context @Dan.  Yes its getting into rhe database successfully,  I just need to display it correctly on the page again after it comes back from the Ajax call.  Especially if there are Double Quotes in what was sent to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you even encoding the value into `taskDescription_#subtasks.guid#` to begin with?

Replace this line

```
taskDescription_#subtasks.guid# = encodeURI(data.TASKDESCRIPTION);
```

with

```
taskDescription_#subtasks.guid# = data.TASKDESCRIPTION;
```

And now this line

```
$('##description-#subtasks.guid#').val(taskDescription_#subtasks.guid#).removeClass('subtask').addClass('subtask-hide');
```

will properly set the new value. jQuery's `.val()` does everything that needs to be done automatically.